# Как изменить размер секции?

Tags: reverse-engineering, elf, radare2

я запускаю радар командой `r2 -A -w a.out`

```
[0x00210158]> iS ~.text
1   0x00000158   0xc 0x00210158    0xc -r-x PROGBITS .text
[0x00210158]> iO r/.text/16
delta: 4
-> elf section ()
-> elf section (.text)
-> elf section (.data)
-> elf section (.bss)
-> elf section (.comment)
-> elf section (.symtab)
-> elf section (.shstrtab)
-> elf section (.strtab)
-> program header (0x00000040)
-> program header (0x00000000)
-> program header (0x00000158)
-> program header (0x00000168)
-> program header (0x00000000)
COPY FROM 0x00000164
COPY TO 0x00000168
Shifted 4 byte(s)
[0x00210158]> iS ~.text
1   0x00000158   0xc 0x00210158    0xc -r-x PROGBITS .text
```

Размер секции .text не меняется